# How to define backslash as keybinding in AUCTeX

Tags: key-bindings, auctex, latex

I have inserted the following code in my init file.  This code insert a space+\ (ie, " \") when typing `\` in a buffer.

Despite the fact that the function `ddd` works without problem in any buffer, the shortcut `\` doesn't work when the file is in LaTeX mode (AUCTeX).

Is there any solution to solve this problem, i.e. typing `\` executes the function `ddd`? The function `ddd` is just an example, the same problem occurs for any function I bind to the backslash.

```
(defun ddd ()
  "Insert a dollar sign with a space in front."
  (interactive)
  (insert " \\"))

(global-set-key (kbd "\\") 'ddd)
```

Comment: This is a Bad Idea™ – I would not recommend this to any user of AUCTeX, but your workflow is yours…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using AUCTeX, `\` is bound to `TeX-insert-backslash` by default, which you can discover by entering `C-h k \` (ie, `describe-key`) when in a buffer in `latex-mode`.

If you really want to override `TeX-insert-backslash` with `ddd`, define the key in the `LaTeX-mode-map` as such:

```
(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "\\") #'ddd)
```

You need to bind this key *after* loading AUCTeX so that Emacs knows about the keymap -- you could, for example, do an `eval-after-load` to achieve this:

```
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "\\") #'ddd))
```